# Getting a value from another two models at the same time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Basically I have a function within a controller which is

```
public function get_all_clubs($city)
{
    $city           = ucwords($city);
    $city_des       = Town::where('town', $city)->value('town_desc');
    $clubs          = Club::get()->where('city', $city)->where('profile_enabled', '1');
    $events         = Event::where('club_id', $clubs->first()->id)->get();
    $lowercase_city = Str::lower($city);
    return view('frontend.pages.allclubs', compact('clubs', 'lowercase_city', 'city_des', 'events', 'flag'));
}
```

The events and the club tables are related using an id as you might have figured out. I have been able to get the events associated to a city based on the club_id. In my view I am echoing each event using the 
@foreach Laravel syntax. The problem however is I need to create an hyperlink for each event on on my view. The routes are structred in the way below:

```
<a href="{{ route('event.show_event', [$club->slug, $event->slug]) }}">
```

Effectively, I need to pass the **$event->slug** which I already have and also the **$club->slug** which is what my question is, how do I get hold of this variable during my @foreach loop. Please note I am an intermediate Laravel/php developer.

My view is as follows

```
@foreach ($events as $event)
@if ( ( (strtotime((str_replace('/', '-', $event->date))))  >= (strtotime("today")) ) && ($event->event_private))
  @php $flag='1'; @endphp
      <li>                                     
         <div class="widget-posts-body">
            <a href= "">  <h6 class="widget-posts-title">  {{$event->title}}  </h6>  </a>

         </div>
      </li>
@endif
@if ( ($loop->index) == '10' )
    @break
    @endif
    @endforeach

@if($flag != '1')
    <li>
        <p> There are no events live at this time. Please check back later</p>                 
    </li>
@endif
```

Comment: please add your foreach loop

Comment: I have now done

Comment: you want to get the slug from Club model when looping Events right ?
If so then what is the relationship between Club and Events models ?

Comment: One club can have many events, and one event will have just one club. So the event table has a column for club_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a one to one relation in event model to club like this:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function club()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Club::class);
}
```

then call it in view like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('event.show_event', [$event->club->slug, $event->slug]) }}">
```